# How to disable drag and drop functionality in direct list web part on the page of sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part

I have a test.aspx page on which i have inserted a web part i.e. OOTB web part which is a library. According to the requirements, I need to disable drag and drop functionality for the users. User will not be able to add any documents on this web part, web part will only show them the list view of all the documents in the library. I changed the "style" to"Shaded" used css but still no success.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, this question relates to web part, while the proposed duplicate discusses Library view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add following details on the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /*-- Hide Drag & Drop --*/
    caption.ms-dragDropAttract {
        caption-side: bottom;
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*-- Stop Drag & Drop --*/
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        g_uploadType = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
        SPDragDropManager.DragDropMode = DragDropMode.NOTSUPPORTED;
        SPDragDropManager.DargDropMode.style.display = "none";
    }, "DragDrop.js");
</script>
```